# PHP stop negative time being displayed

Tags: php, ajax, datetime, time

Good day.

I have a script which displays time until an event starts: My script looks like this:

```
$gameDate = $row['event_date'];

if($gameDate !== $lastDate){
    $calcDate = $gameDate.$time;
    $calcDate = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $gameDate));        
    $remaining = $calcDate - time();
    $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
    $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);

if($days_remaining < 0 && $hours_remaining < 0){
    echo''; 
}

if($days_remaining == 0){
    echo 'Starts In: <span class="timeSpan">'.$hours_remaining.'</span> Hours';
}
else if($days_remaining != 0){
    echo' Starts In: <span class="timeSpan">'.$days_remaining.'</span> Days And <span class="timeSpan">'.$hours_remaining.'</span>Hours';       
}
```

My script works perfectly, infact it works so good that it continues to count even if the event has expired thus:

**My problem**

[image]

Any idea why it is doing it? My if statment to stop this behaviour looks good for to me...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that even when an event has started and that you don't want to display negative hours either, you need to change your condition to `OR`.

And to avoid the rest of the code executing and displaying negative numbers, you need to put it in an `else` block:

```
if($days_remaining<0 || $hours_remaining<0) {
                     ^^ use OR
  // Event has already started
  echo ''; 
} else {
  // the rest of your code in the `else` block
}
```

Comment: I get what you are saying and I also thought about that BUT what if I use `OR` and then `$days_remaining = `0 BUT `$hours_remaining != 0` (example 12hours) will it not then stop the code from executing even though it should? because 1 condition has now evaluate to TRUE..

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee You are not using `!=`, you are using `<` and that is correct and will give you the correct results. So when the hours turn negative, you don't display your counter. You could of course add an `else if` to display something different on the day of the event when it has started.

Comment: I was using != as an example...but do you get what I am saying if you use `OR` logic only 1 condition needs to be true....right? Thus if there are 0 days left BUT still some hours left until start will it not stop the code from executing...You get what I am saying or am i missing something? Thank you very much for your ongoing help

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee 0 is not smaller than 0 so none of your conditions will be met. There is a big difference between `<=` and `<`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the closing bracket of the first `if` statement is but for the last two, it should be:

```
if ($days_remaining == 0 && $hours_remaining >= 0) {
    echo 'Starts In: <span class="timeSpan">'.$hours_remaining.'</span> Hours';
}
else if ($days_remaining > 0) {
    echo 'Starts In: <span class="timeSpan">'.$days_remaining.'</span> Days And <span class="timeSpan">'.$hours_remaining.'</span>Hours';       
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a go and let u know

Comment: No problem, a question though, what is the point of the `echo''; ` line? I reckon this whole `if` statement could be taken out... ?

Comment: The echo can be removed its just to display nothing when the event expired....just something I tried not very efficient I know

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have two bugs in your code. First is checking whether day and hour is less then 0. I think it should be

```
if ($days_remaining<=0 && $hours_remaining<0){ ...
```

Second bug is:

```
else if ($days_remaining != 0){ ...
```

This check will be true even if `$days_remaining` is -2, because `-2 != 0`. So, this last check should be:

```
else if ($days_remaining > 0){ ...
```